# Overriding magento core scripts.js file: Magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides, requirejs

In our custom module, we have pages similar to the order page. We need some changes in the scripts.js file only in those custom module pages. 
Following is the core file we are using is

> module-sales/view/adminhtml/web/order/create/scripts.js .

In order to override we added **requirejs-config.js** in the following location

> app/code/[Namespace]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js

with the following content

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Sales/order/create/scripts': 'Namespace_Module/js/scripts',
        }
    }
};
```

We copied the scripts.js file in the custom file **scripts.js** in the following location

> Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/scripts.js

The custom module pages are working as we expected. But the modifications are affecting not only in custom module pages but also in the Magento pages also.

Please, can anyone help?

Comment: so you want to do for both or only your page?

Comment: @SunilPatel I want to do it for only my page.

Comment: you can create js and initialize your js for only your page so it will work, don't override it

Comment: @SunilPatel Can you please guide on how to do it?

Comment: can i know which type of modification you did? because if you intilize other js then you need to call that js from phtml file and i checked it is contain lot of files

Comment: This custom JS file is the only file we are using in our module. No other JS files are initialized.

Comment: can i know which change you did? for now you can do like this get base url based on do some condition

Comment: @SunilPatel We just tried to change titles and some text contents in the script.js file.

Answer (score 1):

When you are overriding script.js using  requirejs-config.js it's not only works for your custom module but whenever that core script.js will be called your custom js will be called instead od core script.js.

So if you want to use that script.js code into your custom module only, You have to create your own custom js same as script.js because override means you replaced js code with your own js for whole Magento.

`'Magento_Sales/order/create/scripts': 'Namespace_Module/js/scripts',` means you are overriding core js file so when Magento tries to call `Magento_Sales/order/create/scripts`, your `'Namespace_Module/js/scripts` will be called.

If you want to create your own js file you have to give **custom reference** name to your js file in **requirejs-config.js** like:
`'myscript': 'Namespace_Module/js/scripts',`

Comment: That is what I have done. I have created my own script.js. However, the core file is also taking my JS file.

Comment: you have not created your own js, You have overridden core js

Comment: `'Magento_Sales/order/create/scripts': 'Namespace_Module/js/scripts',` this will override js not create new js

Comment: to create your own js you have to give your custom reference to your js like:
'myscript': 'Namespace_Module/js/scripts',

Comment: It is not working. Now our custom modification is not even reflecting in our custom module.

Comment: It will not work because core script is connected with other script also as a tree scructure but you can use directly that code into your custom js

Comment: copy code of the core file into your custom js file that is not the proper way but have to bind all things which used in core js and use it properly.

Comment: How to achieve this? Please bear as I am new to Magento.